# Test a custom c++ macro with catch2

Tags: macros, c++17, catch2

I have a custom macro

```
#define MYMACRO(a, b) ({if (a>b) {return a;}}b;)
```

I want to be able to test this macro with CATCH2.
Something like:

```
TEST_CASE("Check inequality") {
int result = MYMACRO(1, 2);

REQUIRE(result==2);
}
```

This does not work. I get the error `error: void function 'CATCH2_INTERNAL_TEST_2' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]`
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: you are trying to return an int from a function that returns void. You probably don't want to use ```return``` in your macro